# Could not type any character in TextField with name="lenghts.byDay"?

Tags: reactjs

I have a `TextField`.

this is my structure data

```
Tour {      
         id="";
         name="";
         description="";
        lenghts = {
              byDay   : ""
             ,byHour : ""
          }
    }
```

I use the function to daynamic set value to state.

```
handleChange  (event)  {
        event.preventDefault();
        var field = event.target.name;
        var value = event.target.value;

        this.setState({
          [field]: value
        });
      };
```

for use this function i must use `name="lenghts.byDay"` to dynamic set value.

```
 <TextField
                                className={styles.textField} 
                                label="Day" 
                                type="text"
                                name="lenghts.byDay" 
                                onChange={this.handleChange}
                                margin="normal"
                                value = {this.state.lenghts.byDay} 
                              />
```

My problem is:
when i use this plan,i can't type any character in `TextField`!
because the name of `TextField` is invalid.

What is my solution?

Comment: What version of React? What does the TextField component looks like?

Comment: Not sure if relevant, but you have misspelled `lengths` across all your (provided) code.

Comment: @Edgesoft "react": "^16.6.3"

Comment: @Chris  when i change ```name="lenghtsbyDay" ``` remove ```dot```.

Comment: okay, but you still may want to keep it spelled correctly?

Comment: you're missing the value prop in your TextField component - see controlled components: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Comment: also I use ```value = {this.state.lenghts.byHour}``` to set data from state that returned from ```redux```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as follows:

```
<TextField
className={styles.textField}
 label="Day"
 type="text"  
onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'lenghts.byDay'} margin="normal" />
```

In your function handler:

```
 handleChange (field, event) {
 event.preventDefault(); 
 var value = event.target.value; 
 this.setState({
     [field]: value
 });
 };
```

Hope it could help

Comment: Is the name attr dynamic? Have you tried with courly braces? I.e name={lengths.byDay}?

Comment: dynamic means auto set ```this.setState({ [field]: value });```. with ```courly braces``` No,I try.

Comment: I tried ```name={this.state.lenghts.byHour}``` it is not working.

Comment: when i comment the```value = {this.state.lenghts.byDay} ``` it allow me to add characters.

Comment: So, let me get this straight, are you trying to get name attr value from state? If so, which is the motive?

Comment: **No**,i used a ```Redux``` for get data from ```firebase``` and use```mapStateToProps``` then set props to ```this.state``` with ```componentWillReceiveProps``` ,for **edit form**.

Comment: but i trying get value from state

Comment: Is this TextField a Material-UI component?

Comment: yes.based my plan:```handleChange  (event)``` in first post,currently,setstate to ```lenghts.byDay: "20"``` and the initial state is ```this.state.lenghts.byDay```.actually rest value by state value.

Comment: I think must be change my ```handleChange (event)``` that work for name of ```textField``` by **.**. it must set data to nested object.

Comment: Could you edit your code and add your state and your render function? I think there's another way to do what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

**my problem is solved**
**Thank a lot** to All,
Special to @vitomadio

based my plan:

```
handleChange  (event)  {
        event.preventDefault();
        var field = event.target.name;
        var value = event.target.value;

        this.setState({
          [field]: value
        });
      };
```

currently,setstate to `lenghts.byDay: "20"` and the initial state is `this.state.lenghts.byDay`
when i type character to input,`this.state.lenghts.byDay` replaced in value
this is reason for **i can't type any character**.

I change the plan in `handleChange (event)`.

```
handleChange(event) {
    console.log('handleChange');
    event.preventDefault();
    var field = event.target.name;
    var value = event.target.value;

    if (field.includes('.')) {
      var fieldSplit = field.split(".");

      var field0=fieldSplit[0];
      var field1=fieldSplit[1];     

      this.setState(prevState => (
        {
            ...prevState,
            [field0]:{...prevState[field0],[field1] : value}
        }
    ));
    } else {
      this.setState({
        [field]: value
      });
    }
  };
```

and now setSate data to

```
lenghts {
    byDay: "20"
 }
```